# Imputing missing gaps in irregular time series

Tags: time-series, data-imputation, state-space-models, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am currently working with time series data that was sampled at irregular time intervals. There are some gaps of missing data, i.e. a bunch of subsequent observations are missing every now and then. Particularly, these observations are missing completely (all features and the timestamp).

I'm wondering what imputation method makes most sense here. My experience in this field is limited and the most promising ideas that I stumbled upon are:

- State-Space Models with Kalman Filters
- ARIMA models (problem: I read that ARIMA models implicitly assume regularly spaced time series. Maybe a transformation from irregular to regular series might make sense).

I'm thankful for any opinions, papers (maybe a good review paper), et cetera.

Comment: Do you know that the series was sampled at time $t$, even if observations were not conserved? Or don't you even know that a sample was taken at time $t$? If the latter, how would you know at which time points to impute? Finally, are you trying to forecast the imputed series, or is the imputed series in itself of interest?

Comment: The imputed series in itself is of interest. I do know the time point where the missing gap starts and know where it ends. And I do know that some events happened in this gap. I can only estimate the exact number of events (based on existing data) and their timestamps.